# Mongoose: Remove Schema and all items from its DBRef array

Tags: express, mongoose

I'm fairly new to NodeJS and Mongo and I was wondering if someone could help me out with this. I'd like to remove a schema that is a blog post which contains an array that references "Comment" schemas.

Here are the models:

```
var blogSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    author: String,
    body: String,
    likes: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    comments: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment' }],
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});

var commentSchema = new Schema({
    body: String,
    author: String,
    post: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Post'}
});
```

This is how I find my blog post:

```
router.param('post', function(req, res, next, id){
    var query = Blog.findById(id);

    query.exec(function (err, blogPost){
        if(err){
            return next(err);
        }
        if(!blogPost){
            return next(new Error("Can't find post"));
        }
        req.blogPost = blogPost;
        return next();
    });
});
```

Here is the code I'm trying to figure out:

```
router.delete('/posts/:post/remove', function(req, res, next){
    var postToRemove = req.blogPost;
    postToRemove.remove(function(req, res, next){
    //... what should I do in here?
    }
}
```

Thanks for you help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the post query parameter is the title of the post being removed, you could try the following **[syntax](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.remove)**:

```
router.delete('/posts/:post/remove', function(req, res, next){
    var postToRemove = req.params.post;
    Blog.remove({title: postToRemove}, function(req, res, next){
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.json(post);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the **`findOneAndRemove()`** method:

```
router.delete('/posts/:post/remove', function(req, res, next){
    var postToRemove = req.params.post;
    Blog.findOneAndRemove({title: postToRemove}, function(req, res, next){
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.json(post);
    }
}
```

or if you know the id beforehand, you can use the **`findByIdAndRemove()`** method as follows:

```
router.delete('/posts/:id/remove', function(req, res, next){
    Blog.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, req.body, function (err, post) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.json(post);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The post query parameter actually returns a Blog schema that was found by its id. Also, would the methods you have shown above delete all of the comments as well?

Comment: Comments.remove().exec(function(err){});  removes all